# How to use python to transform one line to another by polynomial regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I use python, pandas/numpy/statsmodel to transform one line to another.

For example, I want to transform the orange line into the blue line. What polynomial fitting algorithm/package can I used to find the math operation can transform the orange line to blue line?

[image]

Comment: what is the relation between the 2 lines? is it d/dx?

Comment: @IshanJ. The objective is to find the relation, to find the math operation that transform one line to the other.